# Node.js transform stream - Find the source name in _transform function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have installed node.js on Windows 7, and I am using basic example of Transform stream to unzip log files in a directory and read log files asynchronously using _transform function.

This process is very fast, but now I have a problem:

I need to map source filename to the filtered lines. I tried appending filename to the filtered line in on.readable event but its incorrect since data comes out asynchronously from multiple files so maps everything to a single filename. I tried some code like below but this throws error saying too many event listeners created.

```
source.pipe(gunzip).pipe(liner).pipe(new Upper(filename).pipe(process.stdout));
```

Comment: Update: I tested the below pipeline for a single file it works fine. I tried to use the pipeline in callback function of fs.readdir now it fails with same too many event listeners error. How do I use it safely with fs.readdir ?  Below stream pipeline that works for single file stream: sourcefs.pipe(gunzip).pipe(liner).pipe(upper).pipe(outputfs);

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution basically need to create separate pipeline for each line, the improvised code is as below:

```
    var gunzip = [];
    var source = [];
    var upper = [];
    var outputfile = [];
    var liner = [];
    .
    .
    .
    function file(i) {
        var filename = files[i];
        gunzip[i] = zlib.createGunzip();
        source[i] = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/' + filename);
        upper[i] = new Upper();
        liner[i] = new LineSplitter();
        outputfile[i] = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/' + '_' + i + '_outputfile.txt');
        source[i].pipe(gunzip[i]).pipe(liner[i]).pipe(upper[i]).pipe(outputfile[i]);
            }
```

As further steps, looking to use async module to run these pipelines in parallel.